# Network manager split tunneling doesn't work

Tags: linux, networkmanager, vpn

I am using NetworkManager I have a VPN which has a lot of services which can only be accessed via that VPN. Problem is that there is no access to the internet over that VPN. Trying to use split tunnelling. Enabling "Use this connection for only for resources on its network" doesn't seem to work. When enabled it provides no access to resources over that VPN and adds a huge delay for each request to normal internet. I have also tried setting `ipv4.never-default` to `yes` manually. Doesn't seem to help. Without it, I have access to resources over that VPN but have no access to the internet.

Here my setting for ipv4 of VPN connection I am trying to set up.

```
ipv4.method:                            auto
ipv4.dns:                               --
ipv4.dns-search:                        --
ipv4.dns-options:                       --
ipv4.dns-priority:                      0
ipv4.addresses:                         --
ipv4.gateway:                           --
ipv4.routes:                            --
ipv4.route-metric:                      -1
ipv4.route-table:                       0 (unspec)
ipv4.routing-rules:                     --
ipv4.ignore-auto-routes:                no
ipv4.ignore-auto-dns:                   no
ipv4.dhcp-client-id:                    --
ipv4.dhcp-iaid:                         --
ipv4.dhcp-timeout:                      0 (default)
ipv4.dhcp-send-hostname:                yes
ipv4.dhcp-hostname:                     --
ipv4.dhcp-fqdn:                         --
ipv4.dhcp-hostname-flags:                0x0 (none)
ipv4.never-default:                     yes
ipv4.may-fail:                          yes
ipv4.dad-timeout:                       -1 (default)
```